# webmatrix 3 C# SQL Error The parameterized query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

I am having issues trying to update my SQL database with code that should work, I am not seeing what is wrong, or how to fix it.  Maybe a new set of eyes maybe able to point out what is wrong.  Error =

> "The parameterized query '(@0 nvarchar(3),@1 nvarchar(12),@2   nvarchar(8),@3 nvarchar(4),@4' expects the parameter '@8', which was not supplied."

Code is as Follows:

```
Truck_Number = Request.Form["Truck_Number"];
Truck_Make = Request.Form["Truck_Make"];        
Truck_Model = Request.Form["Truck_Model"];
Truck_Year = Request.Form["Truck_Year"];
Truck_Vin = Request.Form["Truck_Vin"];
Truck_Empty_Weight = Request.Form["Truck_Empty_Weight"];
Truck_Assigned_To = Request.Form["Truck_Assigned_To"];
Truck_Assigned_Date = Request.Form["Truck_Assigned_Date"];
Truck_Plate_Number = Request.Form["Truck_Plate_Number"];
Truck_IFTA_ID = Request.Form["Truck_IFTA_ID"];
Truck_HUT_ID = Request.Form["Truck_HUT_ID"];
Truck_Oregon_ID = Request.Form["Truck_Oregon_ID"];
Truck_New_Mexico_ID = Request.Form["Truck_New_Mexico_ID"];
Truck_Kentucky_ID = Request.Form["Truck_Kentucky_ID"];
Truck_Payment_Start_Date = Request.Form["Truck_Payment_Start_Date"];
Truck_Payment_Due_Date = Request.Form["Truck_Payment_Due_Date"];
Truck_Payment_Amount = Request.Form["Truck_Payment_Amount"];
Truck_Total_Payment = Request.Form["Truck_Total_Payment"];
Truck_Commission = Request.Form["Truck_Commission"];

var updateQueryString =@"UPDATE Trucks SET Truck_Number=@0,
Truck_Make=@1,
Truck_Model=@2,
Truck_Year=@3,
Truck_Vin=@8,
Truck_Empty_Weight=@5,
Truck_Assigned_To=@6,
Truck_Assigned_Date=@7,
Truck_Plate_Number=@8,
Truck_IFTA_ID=@9,
Truck_HUT_ID=@10,
Truck_Oregon_ID=@11,
Truck_New_Mexico_ID=@12,
Truck_Kentucky_ID=@13,
Truck_Payment_Start_Date=@14,
Truck_Payment_Due_Date=@15,
Truck_Payment_Amount=@16,
Truck_Total_Payment=@17,
Truck_Commission=@18 WHERE ID=@19";
db.Execute(updateQueryString,Truck_Number,Truck_Make,Truck_Model,Truck_Year,Truck_Vin,Truck_Empty_Weight,Truck_Assigned_To,Truck_Assigned_Date,Truck_Plate_Number,Truck_IFTA_ID,Truck_HUT_ID,Truck_Oregon_ID,Truck_New_Mexico_ID,Truck_Kentucky_ID,Truck_Payment_Start_Date,Truck_Payment_Due_Date,Truck_Payment_Amount,Truck_Total_Payment,Truck_Commission,ID);
 Response.Redirect("truck_list.cshtml");
```

Any help to figure out what is wrong I would appreciate it!

Comment: The parameterized query '(@0 nvarchar(3),@1 nvarchar(12),@2 nvarchar(8),@3 nvarchar(4),@4' expects the parameter '@8', which was not supplied.

Comment: Check to see if you actually have a form field with the name attribute of "Truck_Vin"

Answer (score 1):

You have @8 listed twice, and you're missing @4.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put it back, at first I thought it was meaning in the 4 spot it was supposed to be 8, so I changed 4 to 8, but forgot to put it back, but still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

`Truck_Vin=@8,` should be `Truck_Vin=@4,`

Comment: Yes, I fixed that in my code, but still gives the same error, I thought that @4 was saying that should be @8 so I changed Truck_Vin=@4 to 8 just to check but forgot to put it back to 4 before posting here.  Although it still is same error...

Comment: ok simple math: from @0 to @19 there are 20 variables Right? But are getting 19 values from  `Request.Form[]` and , I think you should pass one more value in the db.Execute() method.

Comment: yes in that block there are 19 Request.Form[""] variables but there is 1 at the very top which is the var ID= Request["id"]  variable which since this is an update query  it pulls that one from the URL itself  truck_edit.cshtml?id=2  scenario.   Which is @19 on the list,  and at the very end of the db.Execute(updateQueryString,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,ID)  setting...

Comment: I tried very hard to reproduce your issue, but no luck. In other posts with same problems solution is to check for null and if parameter is null, then pass `DBNull.Value`. I hope it helps.